# Issue with Loki storing on AWS S3

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, grafana-loki

As per title: I've an issue with Loki (running on Docker) storing its chunks & C. on a bucket of AWS S3.
Loki is running fine, simply it stores its logs in the filesystem rather than in the bucket, and infact the bucket is empty.
What is wrong in my configuration?

In AWS, IAM, I've created a user with programmatic access, and I've give it the following policy ...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LokiStorage",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::__myBucket__",
                "arn:aws:s3:::__myBucket__/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The policy seems sufficient, since I've use it to push in the bucket some files present in the filesystem.
The relevant part of the docker compose...

```
version: "3.8"
volumes:
    loki_data: {}
services:    
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:2.1.0
    networks:
      - my-overlay
    ports:
      - 3100:3100
    volumes:
      - ./loki/loki-config.yml:/etc/loki/local-config.yml
      - loki_data:/loki
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml
```

... Seems fine too: Loki - as container and service - runs smoothly.
The Loki's configuration file, "loki-config.yaml", seems also fine...

```
---
auth_enabled: false
ingester:
  chunk_idle_period: 3m
  chunk_block_size: 262144
  chunk_retain_period: 1m
  max_transfer_retries: 0
  lifecycler:
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
limits_config:
  enforce_metric_name: false
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h
compactor:
  working_directory: /loki/boltdb-shipper-compactor
  shared_store: aws
schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-07-01
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: aws
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: loki_index_
        period: 24h
server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
storage_config:
  aws:
    s3: s3://__myAccessKey__:__mySecretAccessKey__@eu-west-1/__myBucket__
  boltdb_shipper:
    active_index_directory: /loki/index
    shared_store: s3
    cache_location: /loki/boltdb-cache
  chunk_store_config:
    max_look_back_period: 0s
  table_manager:
    retention_deletes_enabled: false
    retention_period: 0s
```

... But, infact, there is something wrong and/or missing somewhere, somehow.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the culprit: there was an error in the docker-compose:

```
volumes: 
  - ./loki/loki-config.yml:/etc/loki/local-config.yml
### Here: "yml", and not "yaml" ──────────────────┘
  - loki_data:/loki
command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml
### Here: "yaml", and not "yml" ─────────────┘
```

Now the compose is correct, and the Loki's configuration file is the following:

```
auth_enabled: false
server:
  http_listen_port: 3100
ingester:
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 1h
  max_chunk_age: 1h    
  chunk_target_size: 1048576
  chunk_retain_period: 30s  
  max_transfer_retries: 0   
schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2020-10-24
      store: boltdb-shipper
      object_store: s3
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 24h
storage_config:
  boltdb_shipper:
    active_index_directory: /loki/index
    cache_location: /loki/index_cache
    cache_ttl: 24h         # Can be increased for faster performance over longer query periods, uses more disk space
    shared_store: s3
  aws:
    s3forcepathstyle: true
    bucketnames: __myBucket__
    region: eu-west-1
    access_key_id: __myAccessKey__
    secret_access_key: __mySecretAccessKey__
compactor:
  working_directory: /loki/compactor
  shared_store: s3
  compaction_interval: 5m
limits_config:
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h
  ingestion_rate_mb: 16
  ingestion_burst_size_mb: 32
chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s
table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: false
  retention_period: 0s
ruler:
  storage:
    type: s3
    s3:
      s3forcepathstyle: true
      bucketnames: __myBucket__
      region: eu-west-1
      access_key_id: __myAccessKey__
      secret_access_key: __mySecretAccessKey__
  rule_path: /loki/rules-temp
  alertmanager_url: http://localhost:9093
  ring:
    kvstore:
      store: inmemory
  enable_api: true
```

The configuration seems fine, since - at last! - the bucket of S3 is populated and Loki works fine.

Maybe.

Oddly enough: the bucket (as said) is populated, but I see that Loki also stores its chunks etc. in the local filesystem:

```
root@ip-aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd:/var/lib/docker/volumes/monit_loki_data# tree
.
└── _data
    ├── compactor
    │   ├── index_19375
    │   └── index_19376
    ├── index
    │   └── uploader
    │       └── name
    ├── index_cache
    │   └── index_19376
    │       ├── 5a22562e87b2-1674059149901907563-1674116100.gz
    │       └── compactor-1674116450.gz
    ├── rules
    └── tmprules

10 directories, 3 files
```

Hence the question: Loki really works as intended? That is: storing both in the bucket and in the filesystem it is its normal behaviour?